# Connect frontend HTTPS with backend http

Tags: angular, mongodb, rest, mongoose, mixed-content

I am trying to connect my frontend (Developed in Angular, using Mongoose to connect with the backend) and my backend (MongoDB) using an API REST, Nginx as a Web Server.

I applied a certificate to the webpage with my domain, and now is running with the SSL certificate correctly.

But the problem comes when I am trying to get the data from the backend using the API i created.

I have an error that says "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://page.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://XX.XXX.XX.XXX/vicidial/non_agent_api.php?queries=query=data'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I do not know what I am doing wrong but i can not use the backend in https mode.

Now using the backend in https, i have this error :SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER.

This is my connection with the backend:

```
'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = require('./app');
var port = 3900;
var fs = require('fs');
var certFile = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/webpage.com/cert.pem');

var options = {
  ssl:true, 
    useNewUrlParser:true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true, 
    sslCA: certFile,
  checkServerIdentity:false
   }

mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false)
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/webpage.com', options)
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Connection Established.');

        app.listen(port, () => {
            console.log('Server running on http://localhost:'+port)
        });
    })
```

Hope you can help me, i do not know what more to do.

Thank you so much.